# How this InstallData works each line in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav, setup, installdata

My questions:

1. **I want know how this works by each and every line of code**
2. I want to add new attribute here
3. Difference between InstallData and InstallSchema

Here is *InstallData.php*

```
<?php
namespace vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $eavConfig;

    private $attributeResource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "skype");

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'skype', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Skype Account',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'skype');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

        /*
        //You can use this attribute in the following forms
        adminhtml_checkout
        adminhtml_customer
        adminhtml_customer_address
        customer_account_create
        customer_account_edit
        customer_address_edit
        customer_register_address
        */

        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**First both InstallSchema And InstallData both method are called when you install any new module**

> Schema setup scripts change database schema, they create or change
>   needed database tables. 
>       If module is installing, Setup\InstallSchema::install() is executed.

**It means it create new table and its fields with its structure.**

> InstallData setup scripts contain entries module needs to insert into
>   database. 
>       Attributes that come with Magento by default,Cms pages, various default groups and roles, are all examples of data setup.

**Data setup is executed after Schema setup, they function in a similar fashion.**

> So come to the conclustion, Main difference between both is InstallSchema is used to make table and its structure. While
>   InstallData is used to insert/add data into table.

Comment: update the data in table ?????

Comment: for update data you need to create upgradeschema

Comment: can you explain i added code line by line